# How to create a lobby system using javascript on django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I want to create a lobby system that users can create a room, other users can enter the room and creator of the room will chose 9 of them to create 2 teams with 5 players. After both teams are set, creator will initiate a command to close the room (at this phase system will generate a random password and send it to all 10 players) And all of these processes will be on AJAX system so, realtime.

I already have authentication system but I don't know how to create this lobby system. What "games" model should look like? My initial thought was; a table with "creator" field, "is_active" boolean and "playerlist" field, but I couldn't figure out how should I put record of which player belongs to which team.

Besides model design, I'm really clueless at the moment about how to design such system with using ajax, please lead me somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To get started with Django, maybe [this](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) could be useful to you. It talks about implementing a real time chatroom, which seems to cover your needs.

Comment: This is a great example which will help me a lot, thank you so much. I'll try it.